# Node js too many redirect using middleware redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, express

In my Node.js application (I'm using express 4.x) I want to check if the user is logged. If the user isn't logged I want to redirect to my login page. Then I do that in the middleware like this :

**Server.js**

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    // if they aren't redirect them to the home page
    res.redirect('/login');
});
```

**Login route**

```
// Login page
app.get('/login', function(req, res){
    res.render('pages/login', {
                error   : req.flash('loginError'),
                info    : req.flash('info'),
                success : req.flash('success')
            });
});
```

But when I add this code in my middleware, the login page is called more than 30 times... And my browser says `Too many redirect`.

Do you know why my login page is called a lot ?

Comment: Is req.isAuthenticated() also called for '/login'? Cause that's an infinite loop.

Comment: I edited my question. req.authenticated isn't also called for /login. But I tried to remove the `if (req.isAuthenticated()) return next();` to test. I just let `res.redirect('/login');` and I have the same error

Comment: Check in middleware that if the current path is `login` , do not redirect so. And for better case, call `next` after redirect

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani Nice solution it works thanks a lot.

Comment: Cool, you're welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You catch in infinite loop because if the requested path is `login` even so redirect to `login` again

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    // if they aren't redirect them to the home page
    if(req.route.path !== '/login')
      res.redirect('/login');
    next();
});
```